# Generate string if boolean attribute is true (karma counterpart to qi::matches)

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-karma

Imagine we want to parse and generate simple C++ member function declarations with Boost.Spirit.

The Qi grammar might look like this:

```
function_ %= type_ > id_ > "()" > matches["const"];
```

That means, whether the function is `const` is stored in a `bool`.

How to write the corresponding generator with Karma?

```
function_ %= type_ << ' ' << id_ << "()" << XXX[" const"];
```

Here, we want a directive that consumes a boolean attribute, executes the embedded generator if the attribute is `true` and does nothing otherwise. We want something that makes the following tests succeed.

```
test_generator_attr("abc", XXX["abc"], true);
test_generator_attr("", XXX["abc"], false);
```

Is such a directive already available in Boost.Spirit?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that enters my mind at the moment is

```
bool const_qualifier = true;

std::cout << karma::format(
      karma::omit[ karma::bool_(true) ] << " const" | "",
      const_qualifier);
```

It feels a bit... clumsy. I'll have a look later what I'm forgetting :)

**UPDATE** Here's a slightly more elegant take using `karma::symbols<>`:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int main()
{
    karma::symbols<bool, const char*> const_;
    const_.add(true, "const")(false, "");

    for (bool const_qualifier : { true, false })
    {   
        std::cout << karma::format_delimited("void foo()" << const_, ' ', const_qualifier) << "\n";
    }   
}
```

Prints:

```
void foo() const 
void foo()
```

Comment: Yeah. I think the `symbols<>` approach is the cleanest I've seen. Updated answer.

Comment: The `symbols` approach is great (although it would not work if the "subject generator" is more complex than a simple string). Your initial approach reminds me of [this example](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/example/karma/complex_number_adapt.cpp) where they use something like `&true_ << " const" | omit[bool_]` (maybe followed by  `<< ""`).

Comment: @cv_and_he Agreed. Perhaps a sort of Nabialek-derivative is in order for more complicated branches (using `karma::lazy` and `karma::symbols<T, karma::rule<> >`)

Comment: `(!bool_(true) | " const")` is probably most concise. Still, a generator directive would make the code easier to read.

Comment: @purpleKarrot I think that fails to consume the attribute, but I'll check later.

Comment: @sehe @purpleKarrot While trying to implement a generator directive, I've convinced myself that if the "subject generator" is complex, you are better served by `boost::optional` and Karma's optional generator operator, so I'd like to amend my previous comment to just "The `symbols` approach is great.". You can find [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/485374e415d99c56) an awfully named (and practically untested) directive that I think does what you want for embedded generators that have an unused attribute.