# Boost Spirit Karma equivalent to Qi matches

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-karma

What is the equivalent to boost::spirit::qi::matches in boost::spirit::karma?
For example I want to generate a literal "array" only if a boolean flag is set true.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502777/generate-string-if-boolean-attribute-is-true-karma-counterpart-to-qimatches

Comment: @cv_and_he hehe. Completely forgot about that one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the specified value form of `bool_` to consume the attribute only if it matches the supplied value:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54bc6c8c9f35df46)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int main() {
    using namespace karma;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        bool b = (0 == i%3);
        std::cout << format_delimited(
                (omit[bool_(true)] << "array" | omit[bool_(false) << "vector"]),
                ';',
                b
            ) << "\n";
    }

}
```

Prints

```
array;


array;


array;


array;
```